# Jquery UI Slider, handle follow the cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have a problem with my slider. For example, when I have 2 big steps and my slider long is over 1000px I have to pull the handle over 500px to jump to the second point. But when I'm doing this handle dont move before 500px :( 
how to make the hand follow the cursor?

Comment: This is just how the slider works. It snaps to the nearest point, so if you're 49% across the slider, then the first one will still be selected. If you only have two options to choose from then a slider seems completely redundant.

Comment: I have 5 options but slider has 1500px so the steps are big. What do you suggest?

Comment: There's not really much you can do other than use a more suitable control. A slider of that size simply doesn't work well with so few steps.

Comment: With an example, it might help to show the issue better. There are some ways to help. Potentially setting the steps to 1000, and then moving the the handle along with the mouse and snapping in at specific points.